# Why does this C program crash?

Tags: c

I've mulled over this for at least an hour and I still can't find out what the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int Level;
    char* Name;
} Base;

Base baseStruct;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    scanf("%s", baseStruct.Name);
    scanf("%d", &baseStruct.Level);
    printf("%s :: Level %d\n", baseStruct.Name, baseStruct.Level);
    return 0;
}
```

What happens is, I go and enter the "Name" string, then when I type and enter the integer the program crashes. What is going on?

Comment: memory, memory, memory, memory, memory, ..&^%(*# SEGMENTATION ERROR!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", ...)
```

This expects a buffer (`scanf` needs to write *into* it) and you give it an uninitialized pointer, that could point anywhere.

Consider doing one of the following:

1. Make `Name` a character buffer instead:

   ```
   typedef struct
   {
       int Level;
       char Name[100];
   } Base;
   ```
2. Initialize it from the heap:

   ```
   baseStruct.Name = malloc(100); /* do not forget to cleanup with `free()` */
   ```

You should also specify max string length in `scanf` format string to prevent overflow:

```
/* assume 'Name' is a buffer 100 characters long */
scanf("%99s", baseStruct.Name);
```

Comment: Max string length is optional from the `scanf` point of view, but in order to ensure that you will get a working program it should be treated as mandatory. Not including the max length specifier will create yet another program vulnerable to buffer overflows.

Comment: @Schedler I'm not sure what you mean. That's exactly what I said in my answer, no?

Answer (score 1):

Name is just an uninitialized pointer to a string. It doesn't point to anything useful. You'll need to initialize it properly to a string buffer. Also, you may want to limit the string through the formatting (like %100s) to make sure you don't overrun your buffer.

Comment: Where do you find a version of the STL for C?

Comment: Well, sue me, I missed me tag that this is a C-specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't feel bad everyone makes that mistake.  The char * stands for a "pointer to a character" but the memory for the string itself is not allocated.

Add:

baseStruct.Name = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

(note my syntax may be off a little)

Comment: Of course, this will spectacularly crash if the user enters more than 100 characters. Using scanf on strings is unsafe unless you're absolutely sure about the input.

Comment: Also, you'll need to cast the result to char *.

Comment: @EboMike This is C. So, no need to cast the return value of `malloc`. @Gabriel `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated any storage for Base.Name.  You're scanning a string into a a pointer that doesn't point to any storage.

Allocate some space for the string.  The problem is that you don't know how big a string will be copied in using scanf.  Suppose you malloc 256 bytes and then scanf loads in a 300 byte string?  Either allocate a string sufficiently large to handle all possible results from scanf, or modify your scanf to limit the characters, like:

```
baseStruct.Name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
scanf("%256s", baseStruct.Name);
```

Comment: The standard says `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so it's not really necessary.

Comment: **Ouch!** You allocated 256 bytes and specified `%256s`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so it is redundant. Alternatively, you *could* use `sizeof(*baseStruct.Name)` if it is likely that the type of `baseStruct.Name` could change from `char*` to `wchar_t*`, etc.

Comment: @Kludge: I think allocating a string sufficiently large is not a realistic option, as the size of this string would likely be exactly the maximum size `malloc` can return under, leaving the program still vulnerable to buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `baseStruct.Name` does not point to a valid memory region. However, allocating a fixed sized buffer is no safer. For a learning exercise, use

```
typedef struct
{
    int Level;
    char Name[1];
} Base;
```

and enter long strings to examine effects of buffer overflows.

For safe handling of input of indeterminate length, use `fgets` and `sscanf` or `strtol` (or `strtoul` if `Base.Level` cannot be negative.

Here is an example:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INITIAL_BUFSIZE 100
#define MAX_BUFSIZE 30000

char *myreadline(FILE *fin) {
    char *buffer;
    int offset = 0;
    int bufsize = INITIAL_BUFSIZE;
    buffer = malloc(bufsize);

    if ( !buffer ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    while ( fgets(buffer + offset, bufsize, fin) ) {
        size_t last = strlen(buffer) - 1;
        if ( buffer[last] == (char) '\n' ) {
            buffer[last] = 0;
            break;
        }
        else {
            char *tmp;
            offset += bufsize - 1;
            bufsize *= 2;
            if ( bufsize > MAX_BUFSIZE ) {
                break;
            }
            tmp = realloc(buffer, bufsize);
            if ( !tmp ) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                buffer = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}

int myreadint(FILE *fin, int *i) {
    long x;
    char *endp;
    char *line = myreadline(fin);

    if ( !line ) {
        return 0;
    }

    x = strtol(line, &endp, 10);

    if ( (!*endp || isspace((unsigned char) *endp) )
            && (x >= INT_MIN) && (x <= INT_MAX ) ) {
        *i = (int) x;
        free(line);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

typedef struct base_struct {
    int Level;
    char* Name;
} Base;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Base bs;
    int i;

    puts("Enter name:");
    bs.Name = myreadline(stdin);
    if ( !bs.Name ) {
        fputs("Cannot read Name", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("Enter level:");
    if ( myreadint(stdin, &i) ) {
        bs.Level = i;
        printf("Name: %s\nLevel: %d\n", bs.Name, bs.Level);
        free(bs.Name);
    }
    else {
        fputs("Cannot read Level", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> t
Enter name:
A dark and mysterious dungeon
Enter level:
3456772
Name: A dark and mysterious dungeon
Level: 3456772
```

Comment: I don't think just using `sscanf` instead of `scanf` will make any difference. You still have to put max string length in the format specifier if using either of them.

Comment: Using `fgets` to read input allows you to adjust the buffer size to accommodate any practical size string by using `realloc`. You can then use `sscanf` or `strto(ld)` to convert numbers. Obviously, you would not use `sscanf` when you are just reading a string.