# Dynamic sized array in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Here is a code snippet I was working with:

```
int *a;
int  p = 10;

*(a+0) = 10;
*(a+1) = 11;
printf("%d\n", a[0]);
printf("%d\n", a[1]);
```

Now, I expect it to print

```
10
11
```

However, a window appears that says program.exe has stopped working.
The if I comment out the second line of code `int p = 10;` and then tun the code again it works.

Why is this happening? (What I wanted to do was create an array of dynamic size.)

Comment: You are accessing an unitialized pointer. That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this C program crash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877665/why-does-this-c-program-crash)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are probably at least 50 duplicates of this, but finding them may be non-trivial.

Anyway, you're defining a pointer, but no memory for it to point *at*. You're writing to whatever random address the pointer happened to contain at startup, producing undefined behavior.

<strike>Also, your code won't compile, because `int *a, int p = 10;` isn't syntactically correct -- the comma needs to become a semicolon (or you can get rid of the second `int`, but I wouldn't really recommend that).</strike>

In C, you probably want to use an array instead of a pointer, unless you need to allocate the space dynamically (oops, rereading, you apparently do want to -- so you need to use `malloc` to allocate the space, like `a = malloc(2);` -- but you also want to check the return value to before you use it -- at least in theory, `malloc` can return a null pointer). In C++, you probably want to use a `std::vector` instead of an array or pointer (it'll manage dynamic allocation for you).

Comment: Yes, I get the memory allocation point. However, the program is syntactically correct. I had used a `;` and not `,` . Have made the edit in question to correct it. So, I still don't get why the code worked without memory allocation when the line with delcaration of `p` was removed.

Comment: @Jatin: Undefined behavior means almost anything can happen -- including the code *appearing* to work, which seems to be what happened here. From the sound of things, your pointer happened to contain an address that was available and not (at that time) being used for anything else that was crucial. When seemingly unrelated changes cause (or stop) breakage, that's a pretty good sign of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

*No memory is being allocated* for `a`, it's just an *uninitialized pointer* to an int (so there are two problems).

Therefore when data is stored in that location, the behavior is **undefined**. That means you may sometimes not even get a segmentation fault/program crash, or you may -> undefined. (Since C doesn't do any bounds checking, it won't alert you to these sort of problems. Unfortunately, one of the strength of C is also one of its major weaknesses, it will happily do what you ask of it)

Comment: Yes, I get the memory allocation point. However, the program is syntactically correct. I had used a `;` and not `,` . Have made the edit in question to correct it. So, I still don't get why the code worked without memory allocation when the line with delcaration of p was removed

Comment: @Jatin I bet if you ran it a 1000 times it may not have. Or perhaps it would have due to a fluke of how the compiler allocates memory for variables. What if you moved the declaration of `p` above `a` - does it still work? This is the problem with **undefined** behavior unfortunately.

Comment: @Jatin for instance I just commented out the line with `p = 10` and it crashes .. so in both cases. This is with gcc v 4.4.3 under Linux

Comment: Well, I am on Windows using code::blocks and it works if I move the declaration of `p` above `a`.

Comment: @Jatin That just confirms what *undefined* behavior means .. otherwise the behavior would be consistent (or should be) across platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You're not even allocating memory so you're accessing invalid memory...

Use malloc to allocate enough memory for your array:

```
int* a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*arraySize);
//Now you can change the contents of the array
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use malloc to assign memory that array.

If you want the size to by dynamic you will need to use realloc every time you wish to increase the size of the array without destroying the data that is already there

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate storage for the array.  Use `malloc` if you're in C, `new` if it's C++, or use a C++ `std::vector<int>` if you really need the array size to be dynamic.

Comment: You can also use, in C, `realloc`. It's expensive, but it's dynamic.

Comment: @Kernald: expensive, but not necessarily any *more* expensive than `malloc` (in fact, `malloc(x)` is equivalent to `realloc(NULL, x)`).

Comment: @Kernald: Using `realloc` only solves half the problem in that you can use it to dynamically resize a memory area.  The other half of the problem is keeping track of how large the array is and how many items are in it.  When you use `std::vector<int>`, it does both for you.

Comment: @Brian McFarland: That's why I specified "in C". But I agree, that's why `std::vector<T>` are made.

Answer (score 0):

First a has not been initialized.  What does it point to?  Nothing, hopefully zero, but you do not know.

Then you are adding 1 to it and accessing that byte.  IF a were 0, a+1 would be 1. What is in memory location 1?

Also you are bumping the address by one addressable memory unit. This may or may not be the size of an integer on that machine.